# Grails query pagination too slow when navigating last pages

Tags: mysql, performance, grails, pagination

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and MySQL to develop my web application.
In database, I have the Candidate table, which has more than 300.000 records. When I perform a query on this table, fetch all records by pagination like this:

```
Candidate.list(max: 100, offset: X)
```

the returned data at last pages is very slow. It works OK for first and middle pages. I think it is a database issue. Does anyone meet this problem before? And is there any solution to solve this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: how much it's slower than previous page?

Comment: There are 100 records for each page, so I have more than 3000 pages. Each of the first 1000 pages takes about 0.5s to load, but last pages (2500~3000) takes more than 6s to load. Very very slow!

Comment: Can you turn on debug logging for hibernate? Take a look at the sql that is being run for the last page. Is it different to the sql for the other pages? How long does it take to run when you run it by hand?

Comment: I think I have faced this. it was specific to mysql. Pagination params aren't naturally used on mysql queries. Meaning, the entire record set was loaded into memory from DB and the pagination happening on the server. This caused the issue you were seeing. turn on sql log and check the queries. I think we got around it by hql and managing the pagination params manually than relying on criteria/finders.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

1. Sort your query. Unsorted pagination may result in different pages on every request. Sorting can be set up as follows:

   ```
   Candidate.list(max: 100, offset: X, sort: "whatever_column")
   ```
2. Make sure there is an index on sorted column

More on MySql sorting with limit can be found for example [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/%20here)

Comment: I have configured the sort params when createCriteria, and indexing on the sorted column in DB, but nothing changed.